# How to convert YYYYMMDDHHMMSS to a date readable by `date`

Tags: linux, bash, date, sed

I have a set of date/time strings in the YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format that I want to convert to something readable by the `date` utility.  Usually, I can do something like:

`date -d "2010-10-01 12:34:56"`

However, `date` does not like the YYYYMMDDHHMMSS:

`date -d "20100101123456"`..invalid date

So, I probably need to refine the string to be in the prior format.  I'm thinking `sed` is the answer, but it gets ugly very fast.  I'm quite certain my strings will be the proper format, so how do I easily convert them?

Comment: I amended your title slightly. Looks like you're trying to get it readable by `date`, not by bash; bash doesn't know anything about reading dates.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

date doesn't allow "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS", but it does "YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS", so:

```
D="20100101123456"
date -d "${D:0:8} ${D:8:2}:${D:10:2}:${D:12:2}"
```

Answer (score 4):

If the format is totally fixed, you could just do it within bash, chopping up the string:

```
d=20100101123456
pretty_date="${d:0:4}-${d:4:2}-${d:6:2} ${d:8:2}:${d:10:2}:${d:12:2}"
# 2010-01-01 12:34:56
...
```

I wouldn't bother trying to use regex - like you said, the pattern gets ugly fast. A lot of repetition of `([0-9]{4})`, even with extended or perl regex. Or you could be flexible and just match `.`; no verification.

Comment: In shell formatting saves significant time and eliminates the overhead load of pipes and external binaries. There's lots of ${} transformations available. And do not forget use [[ ]] so tests are also ran in the same space.

Answer (score 2):

What's with all of these regular expression answers?  The date(1) tool has the ability to use strftime() style date formatting... an an example of converting one date type to another:

```
$ date -j -f "%Y%m%d%H%M%S" "20100101123456" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
2010-01-01 12:34:56
```

So if it's not in the format you want, convert it like that and then use it.  If you just want to set it, you can simply do:

```
$ date -f "%Y%m%d%H%M%S" "20100101123456"
```

Comment: That's valid for BSD, but not for GNU.

Comment: So you're right... a rare instance where the GNU tool is inferior.

Comment: The other instance of inferiority is the license terms. :)

Comment: Be aware that reading a date (see [`-d`-Option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39967972/4575793)) is not a part of POSIX date. But as long as you're not working on distributions like Solaris (OP has tagged it linux and not unix) you should be good. :) [See my answer here for a bit more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56854952/4575793)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
echo "20101106213245" | sed -r 's/^.{8}/& /;:a; s/([ :])(..)\B/\1\2:/;ta'
```

Result:

```
20101106 21:32:45
```

- Insert a space after the eighth character
- [label a] After a space or colon and the next two characters, add a colon
- If a replacement was made, goto label a

You want some hyphens, too?

```
echo "20101106213245" | sed -r 's/^.{4}/&-/;:a; s/([-:])(..)\B/\1\2:/;ta;s/:/-/;s/:/ /'
```

Result:

```
2010-11-06 21:32:45
```

- Insert a hyphen after the fourth character
- [label a] After a hyphen or colon and the next two characters, add a colon
- If a replacement was made, goto label a
- Change the first colon to a hyphen (`2010-11:06:21:32:45` -> `2010-11-06:21:32:45`)
- Change the next colon to a space (`2010-11-06:21:32:45` -> `2010-11-06 21:32:45`)

Answer (score 1):

```
 sed -ne 's/\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6/p'
```

I admit it'S a mouthful. All the .'s should optimally be [0-9] or \d, though I don't remember if sed supports the latter.

Comment: Generally `sed` does not support Perl shorthands like `\d`, `\s`, `\t`, etc but you can say `d='[0-9]'; sed -ne "s/\\($d$d$d$d\\)\\($d$d\\)\\($d$d\\)\\($d$d\\)\\($d$d\\)\\($d$d\\)"'/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6/p'` (though notice how the double quotes force the backslashes to require doubling; you can't use single quotes because then the shell would not expand the value of `$d`).

Comment: tbh I find this more readable then [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4198321/4575793), +1

Answer (score 0):

Either busybox date or bsd date accept a description of the input format.

Busybox is a GNU small utility, easy to install.

The bsd format has been covered in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4197812/4575793), so here is busybox:

```
$ busybox date -D "%Y%m%d%H%M%S" -d "20100101123456" +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
2010-01-01 12:34:56
```