# How do I get the difference between two dates under bash

Tags: linux, bash, date

Exactly as the question sounds. 
I want to subtract say 20120115 from 20120203 and get 19 as the answer. 
What is the best way to implement this in a shell script?

Comment: Have you considered another scripting language that supports dates inherently? (python, ruby, perl, ... in no particular order), Also you could use a script onliner in you bash source.

Comment: @schoetbi I did think of that but was not terribly confident of that availability everywhere. I know that basic bash and date is available in all points of interest but not about the rest.

Comment: @SteveRobillard Indeed it is a duplicate. I went through about 15 different questions all of which had solutions in perl, python, ruby etc but just couldn't find this one... any idea how to flag this question as a duplicate or just delete it?

Comment: @owagh answers to how to delete your question can be found here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
let DIFF=(`date +%s -d 20120203`-`date +%s -d 20120115`)/86400
echo $DIFF
```

Comment: How come date recognized that string is in the format YYYYMMDD? Please  direct me to the documentation.

Comment: man 1 date says "The --date=STRING is  a mostly free format human readable date string"

Comment: What if the string is 03022012? Note that I have changed the format to DDMMYYYY.

Comment: @shadyabhi Just try it out and let us know the result! I verified the values in the OQ and get 19 as a result.

Comment: @EugenRieck It is a good solution, however not portable as `-d` is not a part of POSIX date. So as long as OP is not working on distributions like Solaris (as he has tagged it linux and not unix) he should be good. :)

Comment: As the OQ has the `linux` tag and all linux distros I know, that carry bash, also carry a compatible version of date, I didn't sweat about this sort of portability

Comment: I get 0 for that. and the man page for let says `EXIT STATUS
   ksh88
       ksh88 returns the following exit values:

       0    The value of the last expression is non-zero.

       1    The value of the last expression is zero.

   ksh
       ksh returns the following exit values:

       0     The last expr evaluates to a non-zero value.

       >0    The last expr evaluates to 0 or an error occurred.
` what if I want to  get 19 as it is the difference between these two dates?

Comment: We are not talking about the exit code (which SHOULD be 0), but about the value of `$DIFF`

Comment: One liner version:  echo $[(`date +%s -d 20120203`-`date +%s -d 20120115`
)/86400]

Comment: you can always check validity of your date string by:
$ date +%D -d "3 Jul 2012"

Answer (score 6):

Proposing this solution which uses `bc`:

```
current="$(date +%s.%N)" #current date, precise to nanoseconds
old="$(date +%s.%N -d `sh some_script_that_gives_a_date.sh`)" #convert output to ns too
diff=$(echo "$current-$old" |bc)
```

`date +%s.%N -d $1` takes an arbitrary date and converts it to [a given format](https://www.tutorialkart.com/bash-shell-scripting/bash-date-format-options-examples/) *(as in this case `+%s.%N`, a `float` of seconds)*. Be aware that

> -d is not a part of POSIX date. [But] as long as [you're] not working on distributions like Solaris ([OP] has tagged it linux and not unix) [you] should be good. :)

(comment by [jaypal singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/970195/jaypal-singh) on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9008871/4575793))

---

To convert it back to human-readable, you can use:

```
date $2 -d @0$diff #Pad diff with leading zero
```

Where `$2` again is a date format see [for example here](https://www.tutorialkart.com/bash-shell-scripting/bash-date-format-options-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

A quick and utterly dirty fix that can be used in scripts (quick and also fast):

This function `gendates` generates a list of valid dates between two dates in YYYYmmdd format (oldest first).

```
function gendates { for dd in $(seq -w $1 $2) ; do date -d $dd +%Y%m%d 2>/dev/null ; done  ; }
```

I use this function for several purposes related to log files, like generating a list of logfile names to check [1]. And it comes handy to count the difference in days too:

```
echo "$(gendates YYYYmmdd YYYYmmdd)" | wc -l
```

YYYYmmdd have to be dates, of course. It only works if $1 is an earlier date than $2 and it's slow for large date differences, but for a period of a few years and to be used in ad-hoc scripting it's quite handy.

And if you happen to have MySQl or similar installed there is a very quick option :

```
mysql -BNe "SELECT DATEDIFF($1,$2) AS DiffDate ;" | tr -d -
```

The last `tr` allows you to enter the dates in any order (MySQL would else render a '-'if the first date is earlier than the second)

*[1] The reason for generating a list of dates is that with that I can generate the names of the logfiles that are in this format: YYYYmmdd.log.gz. I could do that using an asterisk or $(ls), but this is way slower than just providing a list with strings.*

Comment: echo "$(getdate YYYYmmdd YYYYmmdd)" gives me seq: invalid floating point argument: ‘YYYYmmdd’
Try 'seq --help' for more information.

Comment: try to cut and paste the code into a shell. I used this function at a daily base and just checked for good measure (and because I was curious what you may have done)

Comment: `GNU bash, version 4.2.53(1)-release (k1om-mpss-linux-gnu)` gives 
`BusyBox v1.27.0 (2017-09-27 13:20:28 EDT) multi-call binary.

Usage: seq [-w] [-s SEP] [FIRST [INC]] LAST
1`

Comment: with `GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)` I get the first result.

Comment: Might be an issue specific to BusyBox. I tried breaking it on purpose like adding / removing spaces and it either did not work or gave the correct result. Not sure if seq is one of the 300 commands it substitutes.