# How do I get the difference between two dates under Zsh?

Tags: shell, date, command, zsh, difference

anyone has any idea how do i  convert this command available at [How do I get the difference between two dates under bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008824/how-do-i-get-the-difference-between-two-dates-under-bash/9008871#9008871) from a bash to  a zsh command

Comment: The bash command posted is invalid, as you can see if you just copy and paste what you have posted into a bash shell. Are you seriously asking how to convert an incorrect bash command into a incorrect zsh command?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008824/how-do-i-get-the-difference-between-two-dates-under-bash/9008871#9008871

Comment: This is the same buggy command as before. It gives me a _bash: let: DIFF=(date +%s -d 20120203-date +%s -d 20120115)/86400: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "%s -d 20120203-date +%s -d 20120115)/86400")_ . Please upload a screenshot so that we can see what this command does in your bash.

Comment: The command you linked to is different from the one you posted.....

Comment: thats because of those symbols which enclose the dates

Comment: In your question, don't use backquotes, but just type 4 leading spaces in front of the command. This is described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: In a comment, type a baskslash in front of a backquote which is supposed to show up as code.

Comment: i will add it ,but do you know how can i convert it into zsh command

Comment: See my answer. No conversion needed.

Answer (score 1):

While bash and zsh are fairly different, they are similar enough that in your case, that the same command works for both:

```
((DIFF=($(date +%s -d 20120203)-$(date +%s -d 20120115))/86400))
```

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you need to do this more than once, I would make a reusable function for this.

1. Put this in a file called `duration-in-days`:

   ```sh
   autoload -Uz calendar_scandate
   local start end
   calendar_scandate $1        
   start=$REPLY        
   calendar_scandate $2        
   end=$REPLY        
   print $(( ( end - start ) / ( 24 * 60 * 60 ) ))
   ```
2. In your `.zshrc` file, `autoload` your function. For example, if you keep your function files in a dir `~/functions`:

   ```sh
   # Autoload all functions in your ~/functions dir.
   autoload -Uz ~/functions/*~*.zwc
   # Exclude .zwc files (generated when you compile functions).
   ```
3. Restart your terminal or shell.

Now you can use the function above like this:

```sh
% duration-in-days 2012-01-15 2012-02-03
19
%
```

If you want to use this function in an executable script, then remember to `autoload` it in your script.